# JSON-LD tag on Phoenix Liveview

Tags: elixir, liveview

I need to put some JSON-LD content inside a script tag. Today, I’m put the content like this:

page_live.ex

```
defmodule ProjectWeb.PageLive do
  use ProjectWeb, :live_view

  @data_structure %{
    "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    name: "Project",
    url: "https://project.com/"
  }

@impl true
  def mount(_params, _session, socket) do
    socket = assign(socket, data_structure: @data_structure)

    {:ok, socket}
  end
end
```

root.html.leex

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
...
<%= if @data_structure do %>
  <script type='application/ld+json'>
    <%= Poison.encode!(@data_structure) %>
  </script>
<% end %>
...
</head>
<body>
<%= @inner_content %>
</body>
<html>
```

The Poison lib always convert to String. I need a JSON.

How can I put the JSON content inside the script tag?

Comment: What exactly does `Poison.encode!/1` return for you?  It should return a string, but it should be a string representation of a JSON object.

Comment: @Everett yes, it is the return is a string representation of a JSON but I need a JSON.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "a JSON"?  I'm not familiar with that terminology.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean that you need the data bound to a JS variable?  Like `var x = <%= Poison.encode!(@data_structure) %>;` ?

Comment: I need to return {@context: "http://schema.org", @type: "WebSite"} and not "{\"@type\":\"WebSite\",\"@context\":\"http://www.schema.org\"}"

Comment: Perhaps https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.html#javascript_escape/1 might be useful?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but it looks like I'll need to create a view to render the tag content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use the [`raw`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.html#raw/1) function to mark the encoded string as "safe" for use as JSON.

Assuming your controller is passing a map value to your view via something like:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  render(conn, "index.html", foo: %{x: "xray", y: "yep"})
end
```

Then you can do something like this (should be the same using `Poison`):

```
<script>
  var x = <%= @foo |> Jason.encode!() |> raw() %>;
  console.log(x);
</script>
```